# Is vstest.console.exe available on macosx

Tags: macos, vstest.console.exe

I am running my unit tests using vstest.console.exe.
Now I am moving my jenkins to a MacOS machine (because I have to compile a xamarin project for OSx).

Using "dotnet test" does not work (yet?) with xamarin forms (see [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/112826/running-unit-tests-for-net-standard-library-from-console#latest)).

Is vstest.console.exe also avialble on OSX (Visual Studio for Mac is installed)?

I cannot find it anywhere ...

Answer (score 2):

You can run Unit Tests on OS X using NUnit or XUnit, but not MSTest. Further, you can use dotnet core for execution of those tests with the appropriate NUnit or XUnit adapter. However, code coverage does not work yet:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/981